# Setting JNI and subprocess memory limit

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a Java process that uses a native library. This native library is quite resource-heavy, and will spend a lot of ram. Moreover, for some corner cases, it will completely take all my memory and completely freeze my system.

It would be good if the application just crashed in those weird corner cases. But if an exception can be thrown, that would be even better. Is there a way I can specify a memory limit for calls to this JNI library and executions of subprocesses?

I've tried using ulimit -v under linux but it did not work. Ideally I'd like a more portable solution since the program must also run on other platforms.

Comment: There are no real solutions that I'm aware of.  At best, if you knew enough about how this library functions you can interpose somehow on its memory usage and return failures to its `malloc()` calls, for example, but from your description of its behavior this library isn't likely to handle such failure returns well, resulting in crashes or corrupted data anyway.  A portable cross-platform solution would be even more difficult. IMO interposing a JVM with LD_PRELOAD or DLL injection is playing with fire and gasoline at the same time to begin with. A misbehaving 3rd party library adds antimatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly isn't a portable solution.  Restricting resource usage by the current process and child processes can only be done by the OS.  That makes it necessarily platform specific and non-portable.

You have tried ulimit and that doesn't work for you.  (I imagine that is because the limits are per process)  Another alternative is Linux Control Groups (cgroups).

Either way, both `ulimit` and `cgroups` are non-portable, and you set or manage them outside of a JVM.

Comment: *Restricting resource usage in the current process and child processes can only be done by the OS.*  And that's also process-wide.  I don't know of any way to limit resource usage by a *library* linked into a process.

Comment: I meant "by the current process ...".  There isn't a way to limit what a native library can do within a process.

Comment: No *easy* way. As I mentioned in my comment above, it's possible to interpose on memory-management functions such as `malloc()`, determine where the call is from, and limit the library's memory usage that way.  That's a hideous hack, though, and interposing in a Java process is fraught with peril to begin with.  And that also assumes the library is well-behaved if the interposed `malloc()` returns `NULL` when it hits the specified limit.

Comment: Well yea ... but I would say that you are (in effect) changing the library to get it to limit itself.  And, as you point out, even if you can safely substitute the malloc library that the native code uses (without trashing other things), then the most likely result will be that the native library misbehaves.  There's a good chance you will hard crash the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The JNI library is loaded into the JVM process, hence you can't apply special memory limitations for the JNI part only. Only creating a second process would allow that, but that would require inter-process communication between your main Java process and the second process that hists the JNI part.

However limiting the memory usage is a job of the OS - hence there is no platform independent solution.

The only clean way I see to solve this is to modify the library sources (hopefully we are talking about an open source library?) or to configure the used library in a way that limits the memory usage (if it supports this).